# Json converted object sent to kafka has quotes escaped with slashes in .net core

Tags: json, .net-core

when I am serializing my object to json, it is added slashes to all quotes.
same way it is posted to kafka as well. I am trying to see how I can avoid slashes in the json string.

This is built in .net core
string topicmessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

[image: {"channel":"MOBILE","associationTime":"2022-04-19T00:12:55"}]

I want the json to be like
{"channel":"MOBILE","associationTime":"2022-04-19T00:12:55"}

Answer (score 0):

You have to post the full code to define a bug. it could be just a visualization as a string, but a topicmessage format is ok.  Otherwise it could be twice serialized. if you have an error trying to use your json, you can try this

```
topicmessage=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(topicmessage);
```

Comment: From Visual studio it is just a visualization of string as you said, but issue is same is sent to kafka topic as well.

Deserializing is not the problem, Consumer is expecting the message without the slashes.

Same is working with a java producer where it is using Jackson mapper with writeValueAsString to serialize and it produces the message without slashes